# Is there a way to pass a column of hex codes into Matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Given I have a df with 4 columns, such that:

```
x = [1,3,6,8]
y = [7,4,8,7]
names = ['eggs','eggs','spam','spam']
hex = ['#76BB76','#76BB76','#7B8BFC','#7B8BFC']
```

where each element in names has a corresponding code in the 'hex' column.

So far I have been able to group the points using the names column like:

```
fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='names')
fg.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y').add_legend()
```

Here I could use 'hex' instead of 'names' as they are grouped the same way.

However, this generates a plot where I can color the points using an existing cmap (eg cmap='viridis'). I would like to assign the points a custom color that I have in the hex column as this will improve the appearance of the plot. Is there an easy way to do this in matplotlib/seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would just use matplotlib's [**`scatter()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) with the `c` param:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, data in df.groupby('names'):
    ax.scatter(data.x, data.y, c=data.hex, label=name)
ax.legend(title='name')
```

[image: matplotlib groupby scatter]